# Why does the last reducer stop with java heap error during merge step

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, cloudera

I keep increasing the number of reducers and I see that while all except one reducers run quickly and finish their job, one last reducer just hangs at the merge step with this message in its tasktracker log:

```
Down to the last merge-pass, with 3 segments left of total size: 171207264 bytes
```

... and after a long time staying at this statement, it throws a java heap error and starts some cleaning which just doesn't finish.

I increased the child.opts memory to 3.5GB (unable to go beyond this limit) and compressed the map output too.

What might be the cause?

Here is the driver code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.set("mapred.task.timeout", "6000000");
    conf.set("mapred.compress.map.output", "true");
    Job job = new Job(conf, "FreebasePreprocess_Phase2");
    job.setNumReduceTasks(6);
    job.setJarByClass(FreebasePreprocess.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
    job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("/user/watsonuser/freebase_data100m120m_output"));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("/user/watsonuser/freebase_data100m120m_output_2"));

    job.waitForCompletion(true);
}
```

Here is the mapper:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.Context;


public class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text>{

public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
{
    String[] entities = value.toString().split("\\t");
    String[] strings = {"/type/object/type", "/common/topic/notable_for", "/type/user/usergroup"};
    List<String> filteredPredicates = Arrays.asList(strings);

    FileSplit fileSplit = (FileSplit)context.getInputSplit();
    String filename = fileSplit.getPath().getName();
    //      System.out.println("File name "+filename);

    if(filename.startsWith("part-r")) {
        //      if(filename.equalsIgnoreCase("quad.tsv")) {
        //this is a quad dump file
        String name = null;
        String predicate = null;
        String oid = null;
        String outVal = null;
        String outKey = null;
        if(entities.length==3) {
            oid = entities[0].trim();
            predicate = entities[1].trim();
            name = entities[2].trim();

            /*if(predicate.contains("/type/object/name/lang"))
            {
                if(predicate.endsWith("/en")) 
                {*/
                /*outKey = sid;
                outVal = oid+"#-#-#-#"+"topic_name";
                context.write(new Text(outKey), new Text(outVal));*/
            /*  }
            }*/
                outKey = oid;
                outVal = predicate+"#-#-#-#"+name;
                context.write(new Text(outKey), new Text(outVal));

        }
    }

    else if(filename.equalsIgnoreCase("freebase-simple-topic-dump.tsv")) {
        //this is a simple topic dump file
        String sid = null;
        String name = null;
        String outKey = null;
        String outVal = null;
        if(entities.length>1) {
            sid = entities[0];
            name = entities[1];
            outKey = sid;
            outVal = name+"#-#-#-#"+"topic_name";
            context.write(new Text(outKey), new Text(outVal));
        }
    }
}

}
```

Here is the reducer

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;


public class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> 
{

public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) 
        throws IOException, InterruptedException 
        {
            String name = null; 
            String sid = null;
            String predicate = null;
            String oid = null;
            String id = null;
            String outKey = null;
            String outVal = null;

            ArrayList<Text> valuesList = new ArrayList<Text>();
            Iterator<Text> ite = values.iterator();
            while(ite.hasNext()) {
                Text t = ite.next();
                Text txt = new Text();
                txt.set(t.toString());
                valuesList.add(txt);
                String[] entities = t.toString().split("#-#-#-#");
                if(entities[entities.length-1].equalsIgnoreCase("topic_name"))
                {
                    name = entities[0];
                }
            }

            for(int i=0; i<valuesList.size(); i++) { 
{ 

                Text t2 = valuesList.get(i);
                String[] entities = t2.toString().split("#-#-#-#");
                if(!entities[entities.length-1].contains("topic_name"))
                {
                    if(name!=null) {
                        outKey = entities[1]+"\t"+entities[0]+"\t"+name;
                    }
                    else {
                        outKey = entities[1]+"\t"+entities[0]+"\t"+key.toString();
                    }
                    context.write(new Text(outKey), null);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Are you using a custom key / object class (can you share the code)?

Comment: Hi Chris, I am not using any custom key/value. They are all just Text. Let me paste the code.

Comment: Updated the code Chris. It is quite simple to understand.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you have a single key with a huge number of values and the following line in your reducer is causing you problems:

```
valuesList.add(txt);
```

Lets say you had a key with 100m values, you're trying to build an arraylist of size 100m - at some stage your reducer JVM is going to run out of memory.

You can probably confirm this by putting in some debug and inspecting the logs for the reducer that never ends:

```
valuesList.add(txt);
if (valuesList.size() % 10000 == 0) {
  System.err.println(key + "\t" + valueList.size());
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. Yes, you are right. I will have lots and lots of values associated with a single key inside the reducer. So I am wondering what is the solution for this. Does it need an increase in the memory or any alternate solution exists?                                                  Also, I need to iterate through the values twice and so I am caching the values in another list at the sametime.

Comment: Can you describe the outline of what you want your job is trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't written raw MR in a while, but I would approach it in a way similar to this:

Keeping all values for a key in memory is always dangerous. I would instead add another MR phase to your job. In the first stage emit newkey = (key, 0), newValue = value when value contains "topic-name", and newkey = (key, 1), newValue = value when value doesn't contain "topic-name". This will require writing a custom writablecomparable that can handle a pair, and knows how to sort it.

For the reducer in the next phase write a partitioner that partitions on the first element of the new key. Now because of the last reducer's sorted-by-key output, you are guaranteed that you get the k,v pair with the 'name' before you get the other k,v pairs for each key. Now you have access to the "name" for each value corresponding to a key.